# PMD maven plugin html report - how to get a summary?

Tags: maven, pmd

I'm just setting up PMD as part of our Maven build. I've created a custom ruleset and run it with the following configuration in the Maven pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd-core</artifactId>
                    <version>6.28.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
                    <version>6.28.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd-javascript</artifactId>
                    <version>6.28.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pmd-jsp</artifactId>
                    <version>6.28.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>pmd-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This has produced an html report in the target/site folder, which is great, but the report doesn't contain any kind of summary. It is just a very long list of violations in different classes. Is there a way to get a summary of the number of violations per rule? (Ideally including rules for which there are zero violations?) On the main PMD site, they seem to say there is a "summaryhtml" format, which includes this:

https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_report_formats.html#summaryhtml

However I'm not clear if / how we configure that from Maven? The configuration for the Maven plugin includes a  tag, but that only seems to take the values:

xml
csv
html
none

The summary html it meant to be the HTML renderer, but with a property to tell it to include a summary. How can we configure this from Maven? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to specify the full classname of the summaryhtml report:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html#format

> <format>
>
> Set the output format type, in addition to the HTML report. Must be one of: "none", "csv", "xml", "txt" **or the full class name of the PMD renderer to use**. See the net.sourceforge.pmd.renderers package javadoc for available renderers. XML is required if the pmd:check goal is being used.

The plugin configuration would look like this:

```xml
           <configuration>
                <includeTests>true</includeTests>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>pmd-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
                <format>net.sourceforge.pmd.renderers.SummaryHTMLRenderer</format>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: This works but I had to fix the extension: https://github.com/apache/maven-pmd-plugin/pull/41